# How does light actually behave?

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, reference-frames

Senario:

I am walking 5 meters/second and have a laser pointer that I shoot a burst of light from perpendicular to to the path I am walking on.

Would the light travel perpendicular to the path from where I shot it or would it travel "diagonally" because I am walking 5 m/s perpendicular to the direction I shot it?

Comment: [Relativistic velocity addition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula#Special_theory_of_relativity) is what you are looking for.

Comment: @ACuriousMind the walker represents an inertial frame and in this frame the light moves in the direction in which it was emitted. So, I don't understand you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you travel with $v$ = 5 m/s in the x direction and shoot the photon with $c$ in the y direction it will have $\sqrt{c^2-v^2}$ in the y direction and 5 m/s in the x direction (Pythagoras) for an observer which is at rest relative to the ground you are walking on.

[image]

Since you have 5 m/s relative to this observer he will find that the photon moves with $\sqrt{c^2-v^2}$ relative to you (which is less than c), because the x-axis cancels out

In your own initial system you are at rest and the ground is travelling relative to you. The photon then has a velocity of exact $1c$ on the y-axis, since you are always at x=0, y=0.

Comment: From the grounds perspective would any of the light go perpendicular to the mirror or would it all go at the slightly angled direction to stay consistent with my own inertial system? I would expect it to stay in the grounds inertial system more being that its mass is way larger than my own.

Answer (score 1):

You can figure out the correct answer using the [two fundamental postulates of special relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postulates_of_special_relativity). The first postulate tells you that if the beam travels parallel to the body of the laser pointer in the ground frame when the pointer is at rest relative to the ground, then if someone in another frame has a laser pointer at rest in *their* frame, the laser must travel parallel to the body of the pointer in that frame. So, if a laser pointer at rest relative to the ground and aimed in a vertical direction will shoot photons out that move in a completely vertical direction in the rest frame of the ground, it must likewise be true that if a laser pointer is held by an observer moving 5 m/s horizontally relative to the ground and aimed in a vertical direction, the photons will shoot out in a totally vertical direction in the rest frame of this observer. And if each photon is traveling totally vertically in the rest frame of an observer moving 5 m/s horizontally relative to the ground, this tells you that in the ground frame each photon is moving 5 m/s horizontally, and the second postulate tells you the total speed of each photon must be equal to c in all frames (299792458 m/s), so as Симон Тыран said you can use the Pythagorean theorem to determine the vertical velocity, since (total velocity)^2 = (horizontal velocity)^2 + (vertical velocity)^2. Thus, the vertical velocity of each photon in the ground frame must be $\sqrt{299792458^2 - 5^2} = 299792457.9999999583045$ m/s.

Comment: In which direction, for God's sake does this felloe send the light? Upwards? Or horizontally? Does he speak incorrectly, or it's I who doesn't understand? What is that "from perpendicular"?

Comment: @Sofia - I think there were some typos/grammar errors in the original question, but I took it to mean that the pointer was aimed perpendicular to the ground, i.e. pointing straight up in a vertical direction.

Comment: @Hipnosifl I also understood so. Please tell me, is English mother-tongue for you?

Comment: @Sofia - Yes, it is my first language. You were right to think the original phrasing of the question was confusing though, I just assumed the meaning from the context, and from having seen this kind of question asked before.

Comment: I am unsure how your interpretation of perpendicular direction would change your answer, why would this matter?

Comment: @Joe - I was already assuming it was aimed in a perpendicular direction in my answer, so this isn't a "change". That's why I said "each photon is traveling totally vertically" in the rest frame of the observer moving at 5 m/s, I was assuming the body of the laser pointer was aimed completely vertical, i.e. perpendicular to the ground (just as in the image Симон Тыран posted, although there you have to imagine the "ground" is represented as the vertical direction on the screen, so for the laser pointer to be perpendicular means it's depicted as horizontal).